# How to extract the latest created row for each group?

Tags: sql-server

I Have a table below and I would like to group the data by Opportunity_Id and pick up the rows with latest CreatedDate for each Opportunity_Id. I use local variable and table type to load in case by case. Is there any other more effienct way like using a set of query only to achieve the same result? Thanks heaps

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           row_number() over (partition by opportunity_id 
                              order by Created_Date desc) rn
    FROM yourTable
    ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```